# Mobile css loaded on chrome inspector but not working on phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

So i have a website that I am working on, when I use the "phone icon" on google chrome inspector the site looks ok, it switches to the responsive mobile design, but on my phone it's showing the desktop version.

The styles are in the same file desktop&mobile. I have tried on other phones and it loads the desktop instead of mobile.

I don't even know what to do, how to debug, I tried and cleared the cache on my phone, added a ?v= to the css file, still nothing.

Do you guys had any problems like this? What was the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the viewport meta tag ?

Like this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag